# Binding textures or using texture units

Tags: javascript, opengl, webgl2

I am using webgl2 to solve and visualize partial differential equations on a website interactively, so I am using one shader to visualize an array while a few other shaders run computations on the array elements.

Currently I am initializing texture memory like this:

```
function newTextureAndFramebuffer(gl, {initial_state = null, width = W, height = H, min = gl.NEAREST, mag = gl.NEAREST, wrapS = gl.REPEAT, wrapT = gl.REPEAT} = {}) {
    
    // Create, initialize, and bind a new texture 
    const texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, min);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, mag);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, wrapS);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, wrapT);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA32F, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, initial_state);

    // define framebuffer for texture
    const framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);

    // output
    return {tex:texture, fb:framebuffer};
}

// function call
const {tex:inputTexture,fb:inputFramebuffer} = newTextureAndFramebuffer(gl, {initial_state: initial_state});    // current state
const {tex:outputTexture,fb:outputFramebuffer} = newTextureAndFramebuffer(gl);          // next state
```

and issuing program calls with

```
gl.useProgram(timestep_prog);                           // set program
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,inputTexture);             // set input
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, outputFramebuffer);  // set output
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);                 // execute program
```

This seems to work well so far. However, I have seen in other codes, that texture units are used more explicitly, i.e. each texture gets assigned a unique texture unit.

Modifying the above code for texture units, would lead to:

```
function newTextureAndFramebuffer(gl, {textureUnit = 0, initial_state = null, width = W, height = H, min = gl.NEAREST, mag = gl.NEAREST, wrapS = gl.REPEAT, wrapT = gl.REPEAT} = {}) {
    
    // Create, initialize, and bind a new texture 
    const texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + textureUnit);                        // set texture unit
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, min);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, mag);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, wrapS);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, wrapT);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA32F, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, initial_state);

    // define framebuffer for texture
    const framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);

    // output
    return {tex:texture, fb:framebuffer};
}

// function call
const {tex:inputTexture,fb:inputFramebuffer} = newTextureAndFramebuffer(gl, {textureUnit:inputTextureUnit, initial_state: initial_state});  // current state
const {tex:outputTexture,fb:outputFramebuffer} = newTextureAndFramebuffer(gl,{textureUnit:outputTextureUnit});          // next state
```

and issuing program calls with

```
gl.useProgram(timestep_prog);                                                   // set program
gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(timestep_prog, 'u_input'), inputTextureUnit);// set input
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, outputFramebuffer);                          // set output
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);                                         // execute program
```

My question is whether there is a good reason to prefer one approach over the other? Are access times slower for texture that must be bound for each program call? I read that some devices have a maximum number of texture units, so this leads me to believe I should stay away from texture units. This seems to work so far, since all my shaders only need a single texture input instead of multiple.

Answer (score 0):

There's no clear answer to your question as it depends on a lot of factors. Conceptually speaking binding a texture once and leaving it bound is the most efficient, however it may introduce a bunch of management overhead:

- need to handle hardware limitations where you need more units than available
- can't have a texture bound that you're rendering to (even if you don't read from it) so using the output of one pass as input for the next is not possible
- explicitly associate the individual programs to the texture units they use

Furthermore while switching textures has a hypothetical cost associated to it, with GPGPU use cases it's negligible most of the times and with drivers doing all kinds of crazy optimizations behind the curtains nobody can really tell you how your application will fair.

It's also worth to mention that framebuffer binding usually is more expensive than texture binding.